# Getting an error when converting to float to get top 10 largest values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am trying to use the nlargest function to return top 10 values using code below as,

```
df['roi'].astype(float).nlargest(3, 'roi')
```

But get an error of

```
ValueError: keep must be either "first", "last" or "all"
```

the roi column is an object, which is why I use the astype float but am still getting an error

When I try the **keep = all or keep = first or last** filter in the nlargest function I get an error of `TypeError: nlargest() got multiple values for argument 'keep'`

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html)? `roi` is not a valid option.

Comment: Yes, when I try the keep = all or keep = first or last arguments I get an error 

of TypeError: nlargest() got multiple values for argument 'keep'

Comment: When you select a single column `df['roi']` you get a series and you want to use [Series.nlargest](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html#pandas.Series.nlargest)

Answer (score 2):

To use the method as you want, you must change your code to:

```
df.astype(float).nlargest(3, 'roi')
```

Since this syntax works only for `pandas.DataFrames`. If you want to specify the colum by its key, as in a dictionary, then you'll be working with `pandas.Series`, and the correct syntax would be

```
df['roi'].astype(float).nlargest(3)
```

The docs for both methods are [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html), for DataFrames, and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html), for Series

Comment: Thanks, the answer gives me a series output of just the roi column, is there anyway I can get a df of the entire df instead of there are other columns int the df?

Comment: You could fix the column first `df['roi'] = df['roi'].astype(float)` and then do `df.nlargest(3, 'roi')`.

Comment: @Chris90 I didn't understand. You want to apply `nlargest` to the `'roi'` column and get a dataframe as a result or do you want to apply `nlargest` to your entire dataframe?

Comment: @Ralubrusto hi, I wanted to apply the nlargest to my df but also want the output to be a df as well

Comment: Ah, so you just need to use the first command. `df.astype(float).nlargest(3, 'roi')`

Answer (score 0):

For a one-liner you'll need to convert "roi" to a float type first, and then perform `nlargest`:

Passing a dictionary to `.astype` allows us to return the entire DataFrame making selective changes to specific columns' dtypes, and then we can perform `.nlargest` on that returned `DataFrame` (instead of just having a `Series`).

```
df.astype({"roi": float}).nlargest(3, columns="roi")
```